# Encoding string to Get "0x0d”

Tags: c#, hl7

how to `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str)` to Get "0x0d”?

```
var hl7 = @"MSH|^~\&|||||20170718110131||DSR^Q03|1|P|2.3.1|||P|||ASCII|||@MSA|AA|1|Message accepted|||0|@ERR|0|@QAK|SR|OK|@QRD|20170718110131|R|D|2|||RD||OTH|||T|@QRF||||||RCT|COR|ALL||@DSP|1||1212|||@DSP|2||27|||@DSP|3||Tommy|||@DSP|4||19620824000000|||@DSP|5||M|||@DSP|6||O|||@DSP|7|||||@DSP|8|||||@DSP|9|||||@DSP|10|||||@DSP|11|||||@DSP|12|||||@DSP|13|||||@DSP|14|||||@DSP|15||outpatient|||@DSP|16|||||@DSP|17||own|||@DSP|18|||||@DSP|19|||||@DSP|20|||||@DSP|21||0019|||@DSP|22||3|||@DSP|23||20170718120500|||@DSP|24||N|||@DSP|25||1|||@DSP|26||serum|||@DSP|27|||||@DSP|28|||||@DSP|29||1^^^|||@DSP|30||2^^^|||@DSP|31||5^^^|||@DSC||@";
byte[] msg;
int len = Encoding.ASCII.GetByteCount(hl7);
len += 3;
msg = new byte[len];
msg[0] = 0x0b;
Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(hl7).CopyTo(msg, 1);
new byte[] { 0x1c, 0x0d }.CopyTo(msg, len - 2);
for (var i = 0; i < msg.Length; i++)
{
     if (msg[i] == 64)
     {
          msg[i] = 0x0d;
     }
}
tcpServer.Send(client, msg);
```

I send DSR^Q03 Message to Chemical analyser, Here is the message I sent. The problem is solved, but I want to get a better solution.

Comment: Another hl7 problem.  Work a couple of these each year.  It looks like you have string data that is terminating with just a return (unix) instead of a windows return and linefeed.  How are you receiving the message?  If it is TCP streams data can be split any place so code you code may not be very robust getting data in real time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see you want to encode the given command

```
   string hl7 = @"MSH|^~\&|||...|@DSC||@";
```

into a format

```
   header = [0x0b]
   body   = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(hl7); each 64 shall be changed into 0x0d
   tail   = [0x1c, 0x0d]
```

while changing each `64` into `0x0d` within the body. You can try using *Linq*

```
   using System.Linq;

   ... 

   string hl7 = @"MSH|^~\&|||...|@DSC||@";

   byte[] msg = (new byte[] { 0x0b })
    .Concat(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(hl7).Select(b => b != 64 ? b : (byte)0x0d))
    .Concat(new byte[] { 0x1c, 0x0d })
    .ToArray();

   tcpServer.Send(client, msg);
```